# macchanger working then stopping

Tags: linux, mac-address

When I run the following code:

```
sudo ifconfig xxxx down
sudo macchanger -r xxxx
sudo ifconfig xxxx up
```

I do see a change in the mac address when doing the command `ifconfig`. However after a certain amount of time passes, I use `ifconfig` again and I notice that the mac address goes back to the permanent one.

**THINGS I DON'T UNDERSTAND:** 
Is macchanger a program constantly running in the background spoofing the mac address until a certain event happens? What might that event be? I assume that restarting the computer is one type event, but is my previous case of it being reverted after a certain amount of time normal? How do I know how long it will run?

**QUESTION:** Could someone explain to me how macchanger works and especially how long macchanger is running (if I need to modify something to have it run indefinitely, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

I tested macchanger some time ago, and it lost its configuration after a WiFi disconnect. If you are using this for your wireless card, you might try a newer version of wpa_supplicant, which does now implement this function. ( mac_addr=1 in wpa_supplicant.conf will activate it)